# can't accept the right GNU compiler

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, cmake, cuda, cudnn

I want to make the [faster rcnn](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn), I have a VM with UBUNTU 17.10 64bit.
I install CUDA8 and CuDNN 6 then CUDNN 5.
However, when I want to build the lib folder in faster project, I got this

> error: /usr/local/cuda/include/host_config.h:119:2: error: #error --
>   unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
>
> #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!   ^~~~~ error: command '/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc' failed
>
> with exit status 1

Although the default gcc version is:

> $ gcc --version
>
> gcc-5 (Ubuntu 5.5.0-1ubuntu2) 5.4.1 20171010

This is to verify the CudNN version is 5:

```
$ cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2
#define CUDNN_MAJOR      5
#define CUDNN_MINOR      1
#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 10
--
#define CUDNN_VERSION    (CUDNN_MAJOR * 1000 + CUDNN_MINOR * 100 + CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL)

#include "driver_types.h"
```

CUDA version:

```
 $ nvcc --version
    nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
    Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
    Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
    Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
```

I tried some suggestion to install gcc 4.9 but it can't be downloaded!

> $ sudo apt install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9

```
Package g++-4.9 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcc-4.9' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'g++-4.9' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: How did you install cudnn? I have many working ubuntu machines with cuda8 and gcc5. I just installed a corresponding cudnn, which shows `CUDNN_MAJOR 7 CUDNN_MINOR 1 CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 2`. And how about your cuda? Is cuda sample like `deviceQuery` working as usual?

Comment: sudo dpkg -i cuDNN v5.1 Runtime Library for Ubuntu14.04 (Deb)
sudo dpkg -i cuDNN v5.1 Developer Library for Ubuntu14.04 (Deb)

Comment: then : sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.5 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.5
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.5.1.10 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.5.1.10

Comment: sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_static_v5.a /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn_static_v5.a
sudo cp /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/cudnn_v5.h  /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h

Answer (score 1):

> error: /usr/local/cuda/include/host_config.h:119:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!

There is a ABI standard change from gcc 5.0 to support C++11. I think if you want to use some feature of C++11, you'd better to find a new version for cuda as mentioned by @harlelf.

> Package g++-4.9 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source

This is an usual problem when using apt-get, you need add a PPA repository as followings.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-4.9
```